# Best practice for setting a href tag visited property default

Tags: html, css, tags, href, visited

I would like to override a href tag default's visited color property to inherit. However by making this change, every time I click on the link, it changes the color to its parent and not the one I set on it. To overcome this, I use a span to act as a parent element and set the color I want there. I would like to know if this is best practice or if there is any easier way to do it.

Comment: [ask]..........

Comment: Your question is not clear so please if it's not what you asked then just comment on it and I'll remove it, but as I understood you want to make the `<a>` change its color when it's `visited` Well, what you did is totally not the best practice You can control the `visited` state of the `<a>` or any of it's states by just selecting it with CSS Example:- here is your [Codepen](https://codepen.io/H_Abbas/pen/bGNQVGB)

Comment: You should include a [mcve]. If you want it to be the colour that "you set on it" then set that colour on it and just don't change it to `inherit` when it is `:visited`.

Answer (score 0):

After using text-decoration elememt it will show you same color after visit.

```css
.a{
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="www.google.com" class="a">Google</a>
```